# Multiple cron expression using @scheduled annotation in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to trigger a method every last day of month. 
I am using Spring

```
@scheduled annotation  @Scheduled(cron = "${attendance.cron.schedule}")
```

How could I tell Spring to execute for different scheduled time?

I can't use `0 15 10 L *`?

Comment: Do you need to change it on runtime, or after context reload?

Comment: Thanks for response, On context reload

Answer (score 0):

You already started using placeholder `${attendance.cron.schedule}`. So I believe you just need to externalize `attendance.cron.schedule` into your properties file and you should be set.

With Spring you probably end up using [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).
If you are already on Spring Boot, it provides a lot of options to [easily externalize properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).